# Using JavaScript to bind onclick event with arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using JavaScript to create a button element and binding `onclick` event to it. I am using the below code:

```
function getElement (rowObject )
       {
          var element ='<div id="deptNmBtn"><button onClick=getDepartMentNm("' +   rowObject.empName+'")> <span>Add</span></button></div>';
          return element;
       }
```

But here I am passing a parameter Employee Name. The code works if employee name is passed as a single string without any spaces but when passed with spaces its throwing JavaScript error.

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Have anyone faced this error? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: How about stepping into this century and replacing those inline handlers with something else.

Comment: You've tagged jQuery and yet are not taking advantage of its use. Don't use the `onclick` attribute, as HTML belongs in .html files, CSS belongs in .css files, and JS belongs in .js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the inline click handler with `'`:

```
function getElement (rowObject) {
  var element = '<div id="deptNmBtn"><button onClick=\'getDepartMentNm("' +   rowObject.empName + '")\' ><span>Add</span></button></div>';
  return element;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pRdsS/)**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I have marked it. But if you try passing the object itself, its not working. In your demo try passing "rowObject" instead of "rowObject.empName" and alert("rowObject.empName") prints undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quoting problem in your code. Try this:

```
var element = '<div id="deptNmBtn"><button onClick="getDepartMentNm(\'' + rowObject.empName + '\')" ><span>Add</span></button></div>';
```

As you can see, the value for  `onClick` is unquoted. Browsers can parse unquoted attributes, but then they are expected to end up to a space. Actually your parsed code looks like this:

```
<button onClick=getDepartMentNm("Employer Name")>
```

HTML parser cuts the function call from the first space, and `Name")` is ignored since it can't be regognized as valid HTML. JavaScript is executed from "right to left", and the first thing JS tries to do is to get a valid string for function argument. Now HTML parser has cut the function, and JS can't find closing quote, so it throws an error.